# JQuery cannot call method of undefined

Tags: jquery

I have this JQuery function that places a custom scrollbar donein JQuery, with its options.
I'm interested in the section **"callbacks"** where, on event of total scroll of my < DIV > it calls on **my_scrolls_clubber_threads**. I have 4 < DIV's >, each with different id, on my page, and I want to pass on to the function my_scrolls_clubber_threads the id of the DIV. I figured, from my code, that this can be done with **this**. $(this).attr("id").
But it gives me this following error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Where am I wrong ?

below is the code that configures the custom scroll bar (which works partially, it doesn't move the scroll if you scroll it, cause the code is broken by this error).

function i'm calling works perfectly, but the calling procedure seems not to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){

        $(".my_scrolls_clubber_threads").mCustomScrollbar({

                scrollButtons:{
                    enable:true
                },

                theme:"light-thick",

                scrollInertia : 0,

                callbacks:{
                    onTotalScroll:function(){ var this_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
                                          my_scrolls_clubber_threads(this_id); }
                },

                advanced:{
                    autoScrollOnFocus: false,
                    updateOnContentResize: true
                }


        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can leave the `(function($){` and `})(jQuery);` parts. Will be useful when you write a new jQuery function.

Comment: Is that solving your problem?

Comment: nope...it doesn't...but still, it's perfecting it :)

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ this is the page where I got the JQuery scripty from...I don't know if me defining the custom scroll bar for a class .my_class, where there are 4 DIVs with this class, it's working well...probably it's supposed to be working with only 1 class / div.

Comment: Have you tried to play around with `alert($(this).attr("id"))`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33905/discussion-between-adrian-tanase-and-pieter)

Comment: The chat seems to load without CSS, not very useful ;-)